# Optimization problem - rectangular aquarium

Tags: multivariable-calculus, optimization

Find the dimensions that will minimize the surface area (and hence the cost) of a rectangular fish aquarium, open on top with a volume of 32 cubic feet.

$S(x,y,z)=xy+2xz+2yz$

$z=\frac{32}{xy}$

$S(x,y)=xy+\frac{64}{y}+\frac{64}{x}$

$y=\frac{64}{y^2}$

$x=\frac{64}{x^2}$

How do they get $64y-y^4=0$ ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Going from your line

$S(x,y) = xy + \frac{64}{y} + \frac{64}{x}$

Now we take the partial derivatives:

$\frac{\partial S}{\partial x} = y-\frac{64}{x^{2}}$

$\frac{\partial S}{\partial y} = x-\frac{64}{y^{2}}$

At the stationary point we have:

$\frac{\partial S}{\partial y} = \frac{\partial S}{\partial x} = 0$

$\Rightarrow y-\frac{64}{x^{2}} = x-\frac{64}{y^{2}} = 0$

$\Rightarrow x = \frac{64}{y^{2}}$

Substituting into $\frac{\partial S}{\partial y} =0$:

$y - \frac{64}{x^{2}} = y -\frac{y^{4}}{64} = 0 \Rightarrow 64y-y^{4} = 0$ as required.